# TensorFlow and print

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm going a tutorial of Tensorflow.

I would like to display the values of variables `W` and `b`, which are the weight and bias respectively and placeholders `x`, `y` by using `print`.

Is it possible to display?

```
print x,y,b,W
```

What I see currently is as the following

```
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(784)]), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(10)]), dtype=float32)
tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x1006b0b90>
tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x101b76410>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have 3 options:

1. use [`tf.Print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print) this is an identity op with the side effect of printing data when evaluating.
2. manually evaluate the variables:

   `print x.eval(), y.eval(), b.eval() , W.eval()`
3. manually evaluate the variables in a single call: assuming `sess` as the current [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) variable

   `print sess.run([x,y,b,W])`